# What is the notation for the second derivative of a function?

Tags: notation

Is the notation for the second derivative of a function 
$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$ or $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d^2}x}$

Comment: It is $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$. Besides that, wouldn't it have been 10 times faster if you just looked that up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We think of the derivative as an "operator" that acts on a function.  One symbol for this operator is $\frac{d}{dx}.$  If you apply this operator twice, you get

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx}(y)\right)=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(y) = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}.$$

So that's why only the $d$ is squared on top, but the whole $dx$ is squared on the bottom.